# Code does not works for list contain duplicate elements.How can i done the array is distict or not

Tags: python

How does recurssion happen during every iteration? Whats the meaning of self.f2(curr, s1[1:])+ self.f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])

```
class Subset:  
     def f1(self, s1):  
        return self.f2([], sorted(s1))  

    def f2(self, curr, s1):  
        if s1:  
            return self.f2(curr, s1[1:])+ self.f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])   
        return [curr]  
a=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements of list: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    b=int(input("Enter element: "))
    a.append(b)
print("Subsets: ")
print (Subset().f1(a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just simplify the code a little, the core function doing the job here is:

```
    def f2(cur, s):
        if s:
            return f2(cur, s[1:])+ f2(cur + [s[0]], s[1:])
        return [cur]

    f2([], [1, 3, 2])

    # res = [[], [2], [3], [3, 2], [1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
```

Now let's see step by step, whole process:

```
f2([], [1, 3, 2])

= return([], [3, 2]) + return([1], [3, 2])

# expanding the returns respectively

= return([], [2]) + return([3], [2]) +          # first return
  return([1], [2]) + return([1, 3], [2])        # second return

# ok, again I will expand these returns in the next line

= return([], []) + return([2], []) +            # first return 
  return([3], []) + return([3, 2], []) +        # second return
  return([1], []) + return([1, 2], []) +        # thir return
  return([1, 3], []) + return([1, 3, 2], [])    # fourth return

now since all of the seconds lists are empty, the result starts to unfold,

return([], []) = []
return([2], []) = [2]
return([3], []) = [3]
return([3, 2], []) = [3, 2]
return([1], []) = [1]
return([1, 2], []) = [1, 2]
return([1, 3], []) = [1, 3]
return([1, 3, 2], []) = [1, 3, 2]

res = [[], [2], [3], [3, 2], [1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
```